# Custom port number for a WebRole on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have an existing cloud service which work well. It use 2 endpoints (http 80 & https 443)

I'm trying to add a new endpoint on port 4443 but it's not accessible, I got an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when i try to access to my website on this port.

Here the csdef :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="MyService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="MyWebRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
       <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="httpsN" endpointName="httpsN" />
          <Binding name="httpsIn" endpointName="httpsIn" />
          <Binding name="httpIn" endpointName="http" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="httpsN" protocol="https" port="4443" certificate="myCert" />
      <InputEndpoint name="httpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="myCert" />
      <InputEndpoint name="http" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="myCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: What's listening on 4443/TCP, another IIS instance? Is it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is correct. You now have to make sure something is actually listening on that port in your Web Role.

Here's a remote desktop session into my Web Role, note the `LISTENING` state.

```
PS> netstat -an | select-string '443'

  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4443           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I faked two listeners with PowerShell:

```bsh
$listener1 = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener]4443
$listener1.Start();

$listener2 = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener]443
$listener2.Start();
```

`nmap` scan from the Internet:

```sh
$ nmap -vvv -p 4443,443,80 multiendpointwebrole.cloudapp.net -Pn

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org )
...
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
4443/tcp open  pharos
```

All three listeners are reachable.

And the `.csdef`:

```xml
...
<Bindings>
  <Binding name="Binding1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
  <Binding name="Binding2" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
  <Binding name="Binding3" endpointName="Endpoint3" />
</Bindings>
...
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="tcp" port="4443" />
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint3" protocol="tcp" port="443" />
</Endpoints>
...
```

Tested with `protocol="https"` for both ports and a proper certificate as well,

```
$ curl -kIi https://multiendpointwebrole.cloudapp.net/
HTTP/2 403
content-length: 1233
content-type: text/html
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Tue, 30 Jan 2018 20:13:27 GMT


$ curl -kIi https://multiendpointwebrole.cloudapp.net:4443/
HTTP/2 403
content-length: 1233
content-type: text/html
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Tue, 30 Jan 2018 20:13:43 GMT

// Ignore the 403, i had no index page.
```

Hey, free HTTP/2 support from Windows Server 2016! How nice of Microsoft.

Comment: Thank to you, I found the problem and resolved it. I remote desktop and everything was fine. I found that the blocking point was the company firewall after testing from outside... Never believe a network administrator who tells you that everything is fine on his side.

Answer (score -2):

**Note:** You can define multiple endpoints that are a combination of HTTP, HTTPS, UDP, and TCP endpoints. You can specify any port number you choose for an input endpoint, but the port numbers specified for each role in the service must be unique. For example, if you specify that a web role uses port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS, you might then specify that a second web role uses port 8080 for HTTP and port 8043 for HTTPS.

For more details, refer “[Azure Cloud Services – WebRole Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx)”.